# Hibernate JPA can't create index in SQL Server

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Does anyone have a clue why the Index Annotation is generating the error below? AS Far as I can tell the SQLServer2012Dialect can't override the create index SQL used by the Schema exporter as it is not exposed so the Dialect quoted is not consulted... This seems to be a bug in Hibernate unless there is something I am missing.

```
@Table(name = "MakeModel", indexes = { @Index(columnList = "make"),
        @Index(columnList = "model") })
```

Error:

```
2014-07-11 06:23:04,746 DEBUG  org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory Setting dialect [org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect] 

2014-07-10 07:06:28,970 ERROR  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create index `UK_8qa757r67eghwpe0i07hncg55` on [MakeModel] ([make]) 
2014-07-10 07:06:28,970 ERROR  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate Incorrect syntax near '`'.
```

Comment: Please add the sql-server tag. And on sql server this `\`` is invalid.

Comment: SQl Server tag?? yeah I know the backtick is invalid...

Comment: Have you specified the right dialect? It looks as if you specified the MySQLDialect.

Comment: It definitely the SQLServer2012Dialect... IT works for everything except the create index.

Comment: Mind posting your Hibernate version and how do you run schema updating? Do you use commandline for it? How do you configure Hibernate? persistence.xml, hibernate.properties?

Comment: AT Present, I have found that setting hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=false will allow the indexes to be created in SQL Server. From what I see in the Hibernate source, the identifier for quoting is set to ` and that would work for MySQL but it needs to be [ for SQL Server. It seems to be only on some DDL statements like create index.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a name parameter. For example:

```
@Table(name = "MakeModel", indexes = { @Index(name = "I_makemode_make",  columnList = "make"),
                                       @Index(name = "I_makemode_model", columnList = "model") })
```

And please check the [database dialect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html) in your configuration files. It is Property of SessionFactory.

Comment: The name parameter does the same thing. The database dialect is set to SQLServer2012Dialect I am on SQL Server 2012...

Answer (score 0):

The javax.persistence.Index annotation was added in JPA 2.1, so maybe your hibernate version doesn't play well with it.

Try also the Hibernate annotation, which has been supported for a long time now:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(appliesTo = "MakeModel", indexes = { 
    @Index(name="makeIndex", columnNames = {"make"}),
    @Index(@Index(name="modelndex", columnNames = {"model"})
})
```

If this works, you know it's a JPA implementation issue.

As for the SQLServer2012Dialect, it doesn't differ to much from 2008. It just adds SEQUENCE support.

Comment: That's a great thought... However, the Hibernate Table doesn't accept JPA Index and the Hibernate Index is deprecated...

Comment: Try it just for the test sake.

Comment: @org.hibernate.annotations.Table references an unknown table: makemodel

Comment: Is 'make' a reserved word? Try replacing it with something else.